# How to deal with multiple time series in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, time-series, synchronize

I have some smart meter data which shows gas and electricity meter readings at 30 min intervals for about two years, for 16000 households.

The date is stored in separate .mat files, with a datetime variable for the timestamp and a double variable for the actual data. Some of the data has gaps in, from a few hours to several days or weeks. I want to create a timeseries object containing all of the data and a continuous timestamp for the two year period, so that I can then interpolate the gaps.

Another option would be to use snychronize, but for this it seems the 16000 data series need to be in individual timeseries objects, which seems cumbersome.

I have tried this with timeseries objects and financial time series but cannot get all of the 16000 data series and corresponding timestamps into one time series object. When I try to add more than one series to an existing timeseries object, it is added "in series" rather than "in parallel" (i.e. data in the Data:1 column).

When I tried with a financial time series I had difficulties preparing the datetime data in a cell array.

Any ideas what the most efficient way to do this is?
Thanks 
Russell

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of matlab that you have the best idea would seem to be to use the [table variable.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-table.html)

Tables can be used to store disparate objects so that you can have the date/time stamp as well as the meter readings in the same variable.

You can horizontally concatenate the tables (or otherwise [join](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/join.html) as you read them in so that you will now have a time series with a single date variable and the responses for each household.